# Can not save database RDS in AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I am new using AWS and using Putty. I know this is a stupid question, i am searching today to find the answer but still can not solve my problem. I want to download my database from RDS AWS. I have try this to download:

```
mysqldump -h ***.rds.amazonaws.com -u *** -p ****> dump.sql
```

and then insert my password. and it work. when i entered `ls`, then there will be `dump.sql` with green colour.

then i try to download it using this command:

```
mysql -u root -p local_db < dump.sql
```

then it will require a password, what password that mean? Then i click enter without insert any password.

```
 Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

How i can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do, Do you connect to AWS RDS from a EC2 instance? where is the dump file?

EDIT: If the file is in a EC2 instance or server and you want to download it You shoud use filezilla or SCP.

Comment: This is not an answer. If you need more information ask it in the comments.

Comment: i am connect to AWS RDS from EC2 instance. i download my database from AWS RDS named dump.sql, i just dont know how to save it to localhost

Comment: [ec2-user@ip-1**-3*-3*-1* ~]$ ls >>>>
dump.sql.
how i download dump.sql into localhost?